# Perl - Path specified with -I doesn't show up on @INC

Tags: perl

I'm setting up a local perl installation on a machine with no internet connection (for now, I'm just doing a PoC on a VM). I've installed my local perl, `CPAN`, and `MakeMaker` from the RPM repo, and now I'm trying to build `local::lib`, using this command:

```
perl -I /home/serveradmin/local/usr/share/perl5 Makefile.PL --bootstrap=~/local/usr --no-manpages
```

The `-I` path is the location of `CPAN` and `MakeMaker`.

```
> find /home/serveradmin/local -name CPAN.pm
/home/serveradmin/local/usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm

> find /home/serveradmin/local -name MakeMaker.pm
/home/serveradmin/local/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
```

However, it's failing with the following errors:

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/home/serveradmin/local/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /home/serveradmin/local/usr/lib/perl5 
/usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at inc/ConfigCPAN.pm line 15.

Can't locate CPAN.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/home/serveradmin/local/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /home/serveradmin/local/usr/lib/perl5 
/usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
```

`perl -V` and `env -i perl -V` both produce the same `@INC` (neither `PERLLIB` nor `PERL5LIB` are set; actually, `env | grep -i perl` shows no result):

```
/usr/local/lib/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
.
```

The path I specified on `-I` doesn't show up on the `@INC` shown on the errors, which makes it seem like `-I` is not working. But if I run

```
perl -I /home/serveradmin/local/usr/share/perl5 -V
```

this correctly prepends the path to `@INC`.

My google-fu shed no light on this, so any help/pointer is appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you do to your system!? Those modules come with Perl!

Comment: Looks like you copied a Perl that was installed in one directory into another. Any reason don't just properly install Perl in `/home/serveradmin/local/usr/share/`?

Comment: @ikegami I installed perl from the CentOS repository RPM, by running `rpm2cpio perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.i686.rpm | cpio -idm --quiet`.

Comment: @ikegami Yes I do, as I said above: "this correctly prepends the path to `@INC`". It's the first entry in `@INC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Makefile.PL` is probably launching another instance of `perl`, but without respecifying the `-I` option (since it has no idea it needs to). Using env var `PERL5LIB` should get you around that problem since it gets passed from parent process to child process.

That said, I suggest you fix your broken Perl installation instead. `perlbrew` makes it easy to install Perl, but it's quite simple to do it without too. If you opt not to use `perlbrew`, read `INSTALL` for the commands you have to type in and to see how to specify where it should be installed to. Don't forget to pass `-Dusethreads` to `Configure` if you want thread support.

Comment: Yep, you're right, perldoc's list of core modules includes `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`. Like I said, I'm installing from the repository's RPM, not building from source, so I'm not running configure, etc. Since the find command I've shown above for MakeMaker didn't find anything before I manually installed MakeMaker (again, from the repo's RPM), I'd say CentOS/RHEL's RPM for perl doesn't include it, even though it's listed as a core module.